# Десериализовать json с помощью Json.NET на объект с интерфейсом

Tags: c#, json.net

Я использую для  [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema).

У меня есть интерфейс и его реализация, так же есть 2 класс? где лежит "всё" (просто тестовый вариант):

```
public interface IPeople
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    string SecName { get; set; }
}
public class People : IPeople
{
    public string PassWord;
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SecName { get; set; }
}
public class Stud
{
    public string number;
    public string city;
    public IPeople people;
}
```

Проблема с которой я столкнулся, что при Десериализации из файла, выдает ошибку, и в полне логичную, на поле `public IPeople people;` что-то типо: "не могу создать экземпляр, тк у тебя интерфейс или абстрактный класс", как верно реализовать данную процедуру? Я не хочу создавать в данном классе именно поле реализации интерфейса, ведь я не уверен, что туда будет прилетать всегда только эта реализация.

Comment: А где вы видели что вместо типа можно указать свойство типа интерфейс. Вы и без серриализации не сможете нормально с таким объектом работать. `public IPeople people` нельзя так делать.

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь, не понял)
я отлично буду с ним работать, я бы сказал превосходно. В конструкторе передам реализацию и всё

Comment: Из JSON к вам прилетит конкретный тип например People, не может из JSON прилететь интерфейс! Нельзя серриализовать интерфейс, ибо это не объект с данными.

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь, _`public IPeople people` нельзя так делать._ - конечно можно, интерфейс в данном случае ничем не  отличается от класса или структуры

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во дефолту `Newtonsoft.Json` не обрабатывает такие кейсы и выдает логичную ошибку, т.к. он не знает какой конкретный класс создать, а интерфейс создать невозможно.

Если вам нужно полиморфная десериализация, т.е. в `public IPeople People { get; set; }` будут приходить разные типы, то можно настроить `Newtonsoft.Json` так, чтобы он тип сохранял в отдельное свойство JSON (`$type`) по которому он и сможет потом понять, какой тип нужно создать вместо интерфейса:

```
var stud = new Stud
{
    Number = "1",
    City = "2",
    People = new People { Name = "xxx", SecName = "yyy", PassWord = "hello" }
};

var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All };

var x = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(stud, settings);
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Stud>(x, settings);
```

Выведет:

```
{
    "$type": "x.Stud, x",
    "Number": "1",
    "City": "2",
    "People": {
        "$type": "x.People, x",
        "PassWord": "hello",
        "Name": "xxx",
        "SecName": "yyy"
    }
}
```

Но такой способ будет работать только если вы контролируете создание JSON (т.е. оно происходит в вашем же приложении), т.к. `$type` нужно заполнить при сереализвации, если же эти данные приходят от стороннего приложения, то можно воспользоваться другим способом.

```
public class Stud
{
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public IPeople People { get; set; }

    public Stud(string number, string city, People people)
    {
        this.Number = number;
        this.City = city;
        this.People = people;
    }
}
var stud = new Stud("1", "2", new People { Name = "xxx", SecName = "yyy", PassWord = "hello" });
```

Создать конструктор в котором вы будете явно передавать тип (настраивать ничего не нужно, он сам будет использовать этот конструктор).

Answer (score 3):

Так вроде в последних версиях это можно на уровне конструктора сделать:

```
public class Stud {
    public string number;
    public string city;
    public IPeople people;

    public Stud(int _number, string _city, People _people) {
        number = _number;
        city = _city;
        people = _people;
    }
}
```

Comment: В некоторых случаях дополнительно может понадобиться атрибут [JsonConstructor](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonConstructorAttribute.htm) на конструкторе.